# Exportar Banco de Dados do SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou precisando exportar o banco de dados do SQL Server para mandar para um amigo.

Porém não estou conseguindo, queria saber se eu copiar esses arquivos e enviar para ele, se vai funcionar no SQL Server dele (não sei qual é a versão dele).

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\meuBD.mdf
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\meuBD_log.ldf

Esse é o jeito certo de exportar o Banco de Dados ou qual é o jeito certo ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boas Carlos,

É importante saber qual é a versão dele. Você pode copiar esses arquivos sim e mandar pra ele, mas é necessário parar o serviço do SQL Server 1º.

Pode também fazer um Backup e mandar pra ele.

Ou então pode usar o mais cómodo: a função export do Management Studio: Right-click sobre a Base de Dados > Tasks > Export Data-Tier Application, ele exporta a Base de Dados para um ficheiro com o formato BACPAC e o seu amigo deverá da seguinte forma: Right-Click sobre DATABASES > Import Data-Tier Application. E pessoalmente aconselho-o a usar este último método.

Comment: vlw pela resposta

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Carlos,

Primeiro sem saber a versão do SQL de destino você pode acabar enviando o banco e mesmo assim não sendo possível ele importar esse banco.
Para saber a versão do SQL de destino e o seu também e ver  utilize o programa abaixo:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/dba-program/
Nele vocÊ conseguirá ver  a versão na aba SQL > Versão.
Além disso você conseguirá ver muitas outras informações.

Feito isso, veja se sua versão é igual ou inferior a dele, se for faça um backup que é mais seguro.